# convert local spotifyurl to canonical spotifyurl

Tags: spotify

How do I convert a local Spotify track URL like:

```
spotify:local:Aerosmith:The+Rolling+Stone+Magazines+500+Greatest+Songs+Of+All+Time:Sweet+Emotion:274
```

into a canonical Spotify track URL like:

```
spotify:track:489K1qunRVBm2OpS4XGLNd
```

using `libspotify`?

Tx!

M.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often you won't be able to - the Local Files feature is there primarily to play songs that aren't available on the Spotify service "proper".

One thing you can do is perform a search. Local file URIs are always in the form `spotify:local:$ARTIST:$ALBUM:$TITLE:$DURATION`, so you can extract the components and perform a search using the advanced search query syntax for an exact match. (That is, searching for `artist:Coldplay` will only return results whose artist is Coldplay and you can do things like `artist:x album:y track:z`).